# Priority Queue in Java (Max Heap declaration)

Tags: java, priority-queue, max-heap

I wish to make a max heap in Java,but couldn't understand this. can someone explain this to me

**Question**: Given a string, sort it in decreasing order based on the frequency of characters.

Input="tree"

Output Expected:"eetr"

So I need a max heap using Priority Queue,but i didn't get how this code works. How the declaration of Priority Queue works?

```java
    public class Solution {
    public String frequencySort(String s) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
            map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);

        PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue());
        pq.addAll(map.entrySet());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            Map.Entry e = pq.poll();
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.getValue(); i++) 
                sb.append(e.getKey());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

so want to know how this

```java
new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue());
```

thing works for making a Priority Queue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can a lambda expression be used as a Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866032/why-can-a-lambda-expression-be-used-as-a-comparator)

Comment: Thanks for ur help..

Answer (score 0):

You got your answer in a comment, which explains what's happening in that constructor call. I want to explain why the expression `b.getValue() - a.getValue()` should not be used as a comparison function.

Just to review, the reason that expression appears to work is because the semantics for the comparator is such that, when it's called with (a,b), then:

- If the result is < 0, then a < b
- If the result is 0, then a == b
- If the result is > 0, then a > b

So, given two integers, then `compare(a, b)` becomes `result = a - b`, and obviously that works. Or at least it works for the simple cases that most people will test.

But most people don't test for integer overflow. Imagine that

```
a = INTEGER.MAX_VALUE;
b = -1;
```

Now you have a problem. The expression `a - b` results in integer overflow, and the result is `INTEGER.MIN_VALUE`. So it erroneously reports that `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE` is smaller than `-1`.

Any time that `a` is sufficiently positive and `b` is sufficiently negative to cause an integer overflow, using subtraction as a substitute for comparison will give you erroneous results. This is also true if `a` is sufficiently negative and `b` is sufficiently positive.

The correct way to compare is use the comparison method. For example:

```
a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue())
```

In your particular case, this isn't a problem because your counts won't go negative. In fact, in most cases I've seen, this won't be a problem because most usages don't have negative numbers or the numbers just aren't large (or small) enough. But that's not the real point.

The real point is that using `a - b` in place of comparison is an old optimization trick that people still employ today without thinking through the ramifications of doing so. And, although it is faster than calling `compareTo`, the difference is irrelevant in most applications. And it exposes your code to the risk I mention above. It's not a good practice to fall into.

As I've said in the past, "Doing something stupid to save a few nanoseconds is just stupid."