# java using function as parameter

Tags: java, function

```
public static <E extends EntityBase, FE>
FE findForeignEntity(E entities, Function<E, Long> fnForeignId, Function<Long, FE> fnFindIdIn) {
    if (entities == null) return null;
    Long fid = fnForeignId.apply(entities);
    return fnFindIdIn.apply(fid);
}

City city = Utils.findForeignEntity(candidate,
            c -> c.getAddress() != null ? c.getAddress().getCity() : null,
            fid -> cityRepo.findOne(fid));
```

what is "fid" stand for ?  I am not familiar with this kind of usage in java.
Can anybody give me a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a lambda expression? Look at [java's documetation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) on it. Lambdas are a great way of using a function as a parameter, but it will only ever be a one line function. A quick little way of getting around things.

Answer (score 1):

In the method `findForeignEntity` you are passing 3 arguments, first one is `entities` which is the argument to method `fnForeignId`.
The result of the method `fnForeignId` is `fid` and `fid` is the input to your method  `fnFindIdIn` which returns you `FE`(Foreign Entity).

```
City city = Utils.findForeignEntity(candidate,
            c -> c.getAddress() != null ? c.getAddress().getCity() : null,
            fid -> cityRepo.findOne(fid));
```

In this code what confuses you might be the [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). I will try to make it simple. The 2 arguments of your method `findForeignEntity` are `Function`, which is a [`functional interface`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003), which requires a definition.

The definition of the method `fnForeignId` is

```
c -> c.getAddress() != null ? c.getAddress().getCity() : null
```

which is something like

```
return c.getAddress() != null ? c.getAddress().getCity() : null
```

And definition of the method  `fnFindIdIn` is

```
fid -> cityRepo.findOne(fid)
```

which can be read as something like

```
return cityRepo.findOne(fid)
```

These are all lambdas which was introduced in Java8

As @GhostCat has told fid stands for foreign id.

Comment: Thank you, just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, fid abbreviates "foreign id".

If you are asking about the -> syntax: that is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Their main goal is:

> Lambda expressions let you express instances of single-method classes more compactly.

But obviously there is a lot "behind" that concept.

Comment: That will be very helpful.