# callbacks in mongo db java asynch driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to understand how the asynch java driver for mongodb works from this example:

```
collection.insertOne(doc, new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
         System.out.println("Inserted!");
}
});
```

1. its said that SingleResultCallback is a functional interface. what does it mean?
2. when onResult will be called?
3. does any access to the database is with this callback structure ? why do we need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Functional interface is a concept introduced in Java 8. Basically it is an interface with only one method's declaration (except the default and static methods). See details in [What is use of Functional Interface in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003).
2. According to [mongodb documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/async/SingleResultCallback.html) the method is invoked when the operation is competed.
3. Within this structure you have `result` instance that you can operate with if it is not `null`.

Comment: when the operation is completed - you mean when the insert operation is completed?

Comment: @Ohad exactly. Check this API documentation http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne-TDocument-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-