# Access object with functional interfaces

Tags: java, functional-interface

The following situation:

I have three classes A, B and C. 
A is some sort of parent which means A has a reference to the instance of B as well as C. B does not have a reference to the instance of C and C has no reference to the instance of B.

B has a Object (in this case a TextArea) which needs to be accessed by C. C has some text (as a result from some other methods) which should be added to the Object (TextArea) from B.

B should implement a public functional interface. My boss said I should be able to achieve my goal that way. Unfortunately I cannot ask him about hit because he went on vacation. He just left a note.

**EDIT: Found the solution to my problem. The following works just fine.**

Class A:

```
package de.test;

public class A {
    static B b = new B();
    static C c = new C();

    private static void doSomething() {
        c.setChangeString(b.changeString());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        doSomething();
        c.changeText();
        System.out.println(b.string);

    }

}
```

Class B:

```
package de.test;

public class B {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ChangeString {
        void setString(String string);
    }

    String string = "nein";

    public ChangeString changeString() {
        return (string) -> this.string = string;
    }

}
```

Class C:

```
package de.test;

import de.test.B.ChangeString;

public class C {
    public ChangeString changeString;

    public void changeText() {
        this.changeString.setString("YES");
    }

    public void setChangeString(ChangeString changeString) {
        this.changeString = changeString;
    }
}
```

Comment: To do what? Why try to implement a functional interface here? For what purpose? Show what you want to use it for.

Comment: To be able to write into that TextArea. C doesn't know the B and B has the TextArea. My boss wants it that way.

Comment: I don't think a functional interface would be necessary here unless you needed to use lambdas for some reason. Why not just create a normal interface called `Writable` (or something), give it a method called `setText`, then have B implement it? C has to know *something* about B, or they can't interact. As long as C knows that B implements a certain interface, that should suffice.

Comment: You'll need to give us more to go on, the above is far too vague. What do you mean by "C doesn't know about B"? Doesn't know the type? Doesn't have a reference to the instance? Code is worth 1024 words.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Why is _interface_ qualified with _functional_?

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I added a solution to my question. That way it works.

Comment: @PeterPan That strikes me as an abuse of Functional Interfaces. I can't see, in this example, any gain over just using a vanilla Interface.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Isn't every interface with just one method automatically a functional interface?

Comment: @PeterPan Technically yes, but usually you only specifically label an Interface as Functional if you intend to use it for lambda creation. "Abuse" was too strong of a word in retrospect. I think specifying "functional" confuses the issue, since really you just needed to create a plain interface.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay. Is there a name/word if interfaces are used like this?

Comment: @PeterPan Just an "interface"? And I should clarify since I was in a hurry in my last comment. Not all interfaces that only specify one method are necessarily Functional Interfaces. Unless you need the compiler checks outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003), having the annotation is probably more of a Red Herring than anything to people reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you need an intermediary [Observer](http://www.javaquizplayer.com/blogposts/blogpost7.html) that broadcasts changes to interested listeners.

Components can't know about each other, but the Observer pattern makes it possible to keep them decoupled.

*Somebody* has to know about the relationship, but this pattern allows you to centralize it outside the objects themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll look into that.

Comment: Do you have any idea on the functional interface thing though?

Comment: @PeterPan It should be asked: do you know what a "functional interface" is? Unless there's some part of the use-case that you haven't mentioned, I can't see how they'd be useful, or even applicable here.

Comment: I don't know if you mean the functional interfaces built into the JDK 8 java.util.function package.  I would recommend that you stop jumping to a solution and think about your problem more carefully.  You don't want to fall prey to Small Boy With A Hammer syndrome.  Sounds like your pointy haired boss already has.

Comment: @duffymo I added a solution to my question. That way it works.

Comment: "Solution"?  Hardly.  Good luck.