# How to apply Consumer with a map in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, consumer

I have created a Consumer which takes a string and makes it uppercase. I am trying to implement it along with a map to make all the strings in a list to uppercase. I understand that this can be done easily using `String::toUpperCase` but I am trying to do it with a Consumer and I am getting the following error

```
java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: void
    upper bound(s): java.lang.Object
```

Here is my code

```
Consumer<String> upper = name -> name.toUpperCase();
names.stream().map(name -> upper.accept(name)).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
```

I want to know if this is the correct way to use Consumer interface and also what would be a typical scenario where using Consumer would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Consumer will never work for Stream map operation. Stream map operation taking a Function as an argument. 
You can do this with following code also :

```
Function<String, String> upper = name -> name.toUpperCase();
names.stream().map(upper).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Consumer#accept` returns nothing (`void`), so it will not compile, as `Stream#map` accepts a `Function<? super T, ? extends R>`.  Instead of a `Consumer`, you can use a `UnaryOperator<String>` (which is a special `Function<T, T>`):

```
UnaryOperator<String> upper = String::toUpperCase;

names.stream()
     .map(upper)
     .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

You also don't even need to store it in a local variable, as it can be inlined:

```
names.stream()
     .map(String::toUpperCase)
     .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: I understand that I can use the toUpperCase but I wanted to know what would be the best use case of using a Consumer Interface?

Comment: That's too broad of a question for SO to answer.  The answer to your first question, "I want to know if this is the correct way to use Consumer interface", is no.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am able to do it now with the UnaryOperator

Comment: @VarunUpadhyay There is no "best use case" - that's like asking "what's the best use case for a screwdriver?" `Consumer` is a tool, which has multiple uses. A common use (based on open-source projects) is using `Consumer` (and/or other [functional interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003)) to implement a [callback](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

Comment: @VarunUpadhyay when you look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/Consumer.html), you’ll find a [“USE” link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/class-use/Consumer.html) at the top. Clicking on it will show you, where you can pass a `Consumer` to a method. I suppose, the most often used example would be `.forEach(System.out::println)`…

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Consumer` will never work, as you might expect it, because `String.toUpperCase()` returns a new instance of a `String`. Look at following example:

```
Consumer<String> toUpper = s -> {
    s.toUpperCase();
};
```

You see that nothing gets returned. And so the *upper case string* will be lost / discarded.

To do what you desire you have to use a `Function` which accepts a `String` and returns a `String` e.g:

```
Function<String, String> toUpper = String::toUpperCase;
```

With that you then can use the following statement:

```
Map<Key, String> map = ...;
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
    e.setValue(e.getKey(), toUpper.apply(e.getValue()));
}
```

To get what you intended in the first place.