# Java Lambdas Interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

As you all know we engineers works best at nights :) 
I was studying lambdas at yesterday night and I saw a piece of code like that,

```
    BirdCompare tester = new BirdCompare();
    MathOperation addition = (a, b) -> (a + b);
    MathOperation subtraction = (int a, int b) -> (a - b);
    MathOperation multiplication = (int a, int b) -> {
        return a * b;
    };
    MathOperation division = (a, b) -> a / b;

    interface MathOperation {
        int operation(int a, int b);
    }
```

The sample simply assigned lambda expression to MathOperation interface's variable but how ? 
It makes a implementation of method named **operation** which is in the interface and the point I was confused is assignment of that implementation to the variable of interface. I really wonder the idea based on this approach.
Thank you in advance to all.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: "Functional Interfaces"

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a lambda expression to a functional interface type that is congruent -- that is, types of parameters and the return type match.  Please see the [JLS, Section 15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) for the exact details, but essentially:

> A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type `T` if `T` is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is *congruent* with the function type of the *ground target type* derived from `T`.

The [JLS, Section 9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8), defines a functional interface:

> A *functional interface* is an interface that has just one abstract method (aside from the methods of `Object`), and thus represents a single function contract.

It doesn't matter that your `MathOperation` interface isn't built-in to Java, and it doesn't matter that it isn't annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`.  It has one abstract method, and the parameter and return types match, so it qualifies.