# accessing fields inside Java 8 Lambda expression

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Am writting a Linear Search implementation. I have written the code by using Java 7 and 8 as well.

Below is my code:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 12, 34, 94, 8, 37, 10 };
System.out.println("Enter the element to search: ");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int element = scan.nextInt();
boolean found = false;

// Linear search implementation using Java 7 features
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (element == arr[i]) {
        int n = element;
        System.out.println("Element : "+n+" has been found at the index : "+i);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Linear search implementation using Java 8 features
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .forEach(i -> {
        if (element == arr[i]) {
            int n = element;
            System.out.println("Element : " + n + " has been found at the index : " + i);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    });

if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Element : "+ element + " not found.");
}
```

Following piece of code is working properly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (element == arr[i]) {
        int n = element;
        System.out.println("Element : " + n + " has been found at the index : " + i);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But, below code with Java 8 features throwing error for the fields inside forEach loop

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .forEach(i -> {
        if (element == arr[i]) {
            int n = element;
            System.out.println("Element : " + n + " has been found at the index : " + i);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    });
```

An error occurs:

> Local variable found defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
>
> break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch

How can I access `boolean found` inside forEach block in Java 8 features?

Comment: break in forEach lambda ... nope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the message says it already. Note that when working with streams you usually try to avoid `.forEach` (or at least you do not just transform your `for`-loops into `.forEach`).

What you probably rather wanted is something like the following:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> element == arr[i]) // .equals( ??
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("Element : "+element+" has been found at the index : "+i));
```

If you have to deal also with the case were none is found, use the following:

```
OptionalInt result = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> element == arr[i]) // .equals( ??
        .findFirst();
if (result.isPresent()) {
  System.out.printf("Element : %s has been found at the index : %d%n", element, result.getAsInt());
} else {
  // none found
  System.out.printf("Element %s not found%n", element);
}
```

Newer Java versions support `ifPresentOrElse` which might be useful here, e.g. (code tested by MC Emperor, as I have no Java >8 here ;-)):

```
...
.findFirst()
.ifPresentOrElse(i -> System.out.printf("Element : %s has been found at the index : %d%n", element, i),
                () -> System.out.printf("Element %s not found%n", element));
```

Comment: Its working nicely, how i can write a `else` block. if the element is not found in the array

Comment: well... it's time to update your Java version then ;-) I will update the answer to show you a Java-8-working variant...

Comment: @Roland - `OptionalInt` code is perfectly working for me.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not access the `boolean found` but return that value from the stream.

```
int element;
OptionalInt valueOptional = Arrays.stream(arr)
                                 .filter(current -> current == element)
                                 .findFirst();
```

Then, check weather the optional is present or not.

```
valueOptional.isPresent();
```

Comment: This code won't work, since `arr` is of type `int[]`. By invoking `Stream.of(arr)` you pass the `int[]` itself as only argument to the `of` method. Use `Arrays.stream` to stream over an array of primitive integers.

Comment: @MCEmperor There you go

Comment: That's better ;-)

Comment: @AlexRolea - `OptionalInt valueOptional= Arrays.stream(arr)` this code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that, depending on your exact requirements:

#### Indexes

You could of course create an `IntStream` containing all indexes of the given array:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
```

You can then check if the element at the given position is equal to `element`:

```
    .filter(i -> arr[i] == element)
```

We can abort walking if we find any array element equal to `element`:

```
    .findAny()
```

This returns an `OptionalInt`, which contains the first index of the found element. `OptionalInt` is designed to contain either a value, or not. This is better than using a sentinel value (like, for example, `-1`).

You can then perform a certain action if the value is found:

```
    .ifPresent(i -> System.out.println("Element " + element + " found at index " + i))
```

#### Stream over the elements without using index

If you don't care about the actual index, you can also stream the array directly. The `Arrays` class within the `java.util` package provides a method to stream an `int[]`, returning an IntStream, which is a stream designed to stream a source of `int`s.

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(t -> t == element)
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(t -> ...);
```

#### More about streams

The elements of a stream are lazily consumed. That means that the stream terminates if enough elements are consumed to get to the final result. For example, `Arrays.stream(arr).findAny()` only touches the first element of `arr`. You could say that `findAny()` is similar to `if (found) { break; }` in its effect.

---

*Note that you're actually using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). That is a new language construct introduced in Java 8. `forEach` is nothing more than a method accepting a `Consumer`, which is in turn a [functional interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003). You can only [access variables which are `final` or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class/4732617#4732617). The `forEach` method is different from a `for` loop, so you cannot actually use `break`.*