# Functional Interface Implementations and use cases

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, functional-interface

I was just trying to write a functional interface to understand the different use cases.

Looking at the below code which I have written, I understand that I can have different implementations using lambda expressions. Apart from this can anyone show the complex implementations?

Is it possible to use other default method i.e. `addLikeOtherWay` in lambda expression? if yes how in my example?

Why would I have interface with only one abstract method? What would be the use case of having only single abstract method in my interface?

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ICalculator i = (int a, int b) -> a + b;
        System.out.println(i.add(5, 2));
        i = (int a, int b) -> a + b + a;
        System.out.println(i.add(5, 2));
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface ICalculator {

    public int add(int a, int b);

    default int addLikeThis(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    default int addLikeOtherWay(int a, int b) {
        return a + b + a + b;
    }

}
```

Comment: The duplicate link does not answer most of my questions

Comment: The goal of the `FunctionalInterface` is to allow you to make lambdas out of it, hence the fact that it's abstract, since the implementation will be the lambda

Comment: *Is it possible to use other default method i.e. addLikeOtherWay in lambda expression?* What do you exactly mean by *"in lambda expression"* here? I mean you can call `i.addLikeOtherWay(5, 2)` to invoke the method for sure.

Comment: *Why would I have interface with only one abstract method? What would be the use case of having only single abstract method in my interface?* ... One of the use cases for having a [functional interface is its representation as lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010594), apart from which there is always c chance that your interface might not just require being a functional interface which depends on how you design the interface to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would I have interface with only one abstract method? What would be the use case of having only single abstract method in my interface?

To facilitate the use of lambda expressions , which are nameless functions. 
Lambda expressions make code expressive and reduce clutter. It also makes code more readable.  This is based  my experience working with lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible to use the default method in a lambda expression?"  Yes.  In fact, many Functional Interfaces contain default methods.  You need one and only one abstract method in an interface for it to be a functional interface, otherwise there would be other interface methods "unimplemented" by the lambda which is not permitted. But here is how the defaults can be applied.  The `BiFunction` interface below was lifted from the API sources, sans JavaDoc.

The following code works because `BinaryOperator` and `UnaryOperator` extend  `BiFunction` and `Function` respectively.

```java
      BinaryOperator<Integer> add = (numb1,numb2)->numb1+numb2;
      UnaryOperator<Integer> mul = resultFromAdd->resultFromAdd*20;
      BinaryOperator<Integer> addThenMul = (numb1,numb2) ->add.andThen(mul).apply(numb1,numb2);
      int result = addThenMul.apply(10,20); // produces (10+20)*20 = 600
```

The following was lifted form the Java API source files.

```java
       @FunctionalInterface
       public interface BiFunction<T, U, R> {

          R apply(T t, U u);

          default <V> BiFunction<T, U, V> andThen(
                Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
             Objects.requireNonNull(after);
             return (T t, U u) -> after.apply(apply(t, u));
          }
       }
```

In the example code above I could have used `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer>` and `Function<Integer,Integer>`.  But the `*Operator` extensions presume the same type for all args so they are easier to use (i.e. less typing).