# Why can a method reference be inserted in a list of interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, interface

I don't understand why this code compiles without error or warning:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class A {}

interface I {
    void methodI();
}

public class B {
    public void test() {
        List<I> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(A::new);
    }
}
```

After all, `A::new` should be a lambda (as shown when I print  l.get(0) which gives `B$$Lambda$/1/...`), so I don't see why it could fit in a list of the I interface.
(I'm using Java 8, but also [tested with Java 10](https://repl.it/repls/DimgreyUnsteadyNonlinearprogramming))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly how one uses lambdas and method references: by assigning them to a [functional interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010594/why-do-i-need-a-functional-interface-to-work-with-lambdas), an interface with a single abstract method. They don't compile otherwise.

If you were to inspect `B$$Lambda$/1/...` you'd find it's an auto-generated class that `implements I`.

These snippets are all equivalent:

```
l.add(A::new);
```

```
l.add(() -> new A());
```

```
l.add(() -> { new A(); });
```

```
l.add(new I() {
    @Override public void methodI() {
        new A();
    }
});
```

(Note that this isn't a **useful** method. It creates a new object and immediately throws it away. `A::new` is a valid match for `void methodI()`, but it's very likely a semantic error. It'd be better if the interface were something like `A methodI()` or `Object methodI()`.)

Comment: Note that this comes from a beginner's mistake, where they wanted to do l.add(new SomeObject()); but instead did l.add(SomeObject::new); by mistake. However since their interface only had one method (by chance), it compiled and their program didn't work. Thank you for your detailed answer, I didn't know any interface with one method was a functional interface.