# Lambda Is Not Working in Kotlin for Multithreading Operation

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple worker thread class that has a function called execute that adds tasks to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue object.

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.handler
import android.util.Log
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

class SimpleWorker : Thread(TAG) {

    lateinit var taskQueue: ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>
    lateinit var alive: AtomicBoolean

    companion object {
        val TAG = "SimpleWorker"
    }

    init {
        start() // call start method of thread
    }

    override fun run() {
        alive = AtomicBoolean(true)
        taskQueue = ConcurrentLinkedQueue()

        while (alive.get()) { // .get returns the value
            val task: Runnable = taskQueue.poll()
            if(task != null) { // if there is a task in queue
                task.run() // run the task
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "SimpleWorker Terminated")
    }

    fun execute(task: Runnable): SimpleWorker {
        taskQueue.add(task)
        return this
    }

    fun quit() {
        alive.set(false)
    }
}
```

I am able to run an anonymous part as a lambda in Java, but it isn't working as a Lambda in Kotlin. Here is this main part:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.handler

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Message
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var worker: SimpleWorker? = null
    private var tvMessage: TextView? = null
    private val handler: Handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        // using anonymous class outside of arguments
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            super.handleMessage(msg)
            tvMessage!!.text = msg.obj as String
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        tvMessage = findViewById(R.id.tv_message)
        worker = SimpleWorker() // thread starts
        worker.execute({
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            val message = Message.obtain()
            message.obj = "Task 1 completed"
            handler.sendMessage(message)
        }).execute({
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            val message = Message.obtain()
            message.obj = "Task 2 completed"
            handler.sendMessage(message)
        }).execute({
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            val message = Message.obtain()
            message.obj = "Task 3 completed"
            handler.sendMessage(message)
        })
    }
}
```

The execute lambdas are lined out in red and the compiler tells me that its required to return Runnable. That doesn't make any sense to me since those methods return a SimpleWorker.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You aren't creating `Runnable` with this `worker.execute({...})`. Use `worker.execute(Runnable { ... })`. It will probably also crash because of empty taskQueue.

Comment: But in Java, "worker.execute(() -> {" works just fine, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you do `worker.execute({ })` in Kotlin you're using a Kotlin lambda reference which is not a `@FunctionalInterface`. The reason why this works in Java and not in Kotlin is that `Runnable` has the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation on it so you can substitute `Runnable` with a Java lambda.
Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010594/why-do-i-need-a-functional-interface-to-work-with-lambdas) related question.

Comment: May I ask you why it wants to work when writing worker.execute(Runnable {...})? I thought that () -> implies making a Runnable.

Comment: It is because with `Runnable {}` you create an anonymous instance of `Runnable`. It is a shorthand for that in Kotlin.